# Is it possible to use a distributed camera array to fake an interferometric sensor without phase data?

Tags: optics, information, signal-processing, interferometry, camera

Astronomical interferometry is a technique which uses multiple small telescopes to mimic one giant telescope. It requires the phase of the light to be captured for it to work. It is widely used in radio astronomy to get better resolution but it has seen less use in optical astronomy as the high frequencies of near-visible light makes recording and storing its phase data for later analysis impractical, instead requiring that the light from two or more telescopes to be sent through physical pipelines to interfere, limiting optical interferometer's size. This is my understanding of the background to this question, please correct me if I'm wrong.

My actual question is if it is possible to use an array of cameras do what interferometry does, fake one big eye with lots of small ones, without any phase data or actual interferometry. For example if you were given an X by X meter(or millimeter or kilometer or whatever) ideally you  would set up one giant sensor element filling the whole space to maximize resolution and light-gathering. However if you don't have the budget for that sprinkling a few thousand smaller but interferometrically linked sensors around would get you the same resolution though not the same light-gathering capability. What I'm wondering is if you sprinkled a few thousand normal non-interferometric cameras that only record non phase information, luminance, color, and polarization, would you be able to glean any more information from the cross-correlated aggregate of the data that cannot be deduced from the raw data of the individual cameras.

Basically my question can be boiled down to three points.

A. Can many little cameras fake one big camera without interferometry purely through post-processing?

B. If the answer to A is yes can said virtual big camera have a better resolution than the diffraction limit of the individual cameras?

C. If the answer to A is yes what could interferometric arrays do that post processed arrays can't?

Comment: Does the Hanbury-Brown & Twiss experiment count? It is a carrier phase independent, i.e., non-coherent envelope correlation technique, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect

Comment: I'm not sure. I suppose by my standards it would “count” if the HBT effect could produce an image with a better angular resolution than the diffraction limit of the individual sensor elements. Unfortunately I   don't understand enough of the Wikipedia page to tell if that's the case. So I ask to someone more knowledgeable than me, would the HBT effect “count” according to the the standards I have given? Can it circumvent the diffraction limit of individual cameras?

Comment: The envelope correlation does not give better resolution than the diffraction limit of a coherent system, it just gives you an image without the reference phase. To get better resolution than the diffraction limit you need to correct the near field (evanescent modes) but that is a "coherent" method.